# The set of all real number x such that $||3-x|-| x+2||=5$

Tags: solution-verification, quadratics

The set of all real number x such that
$$||3-x|-| x+2||=5$$
is??

**My approach:-**
$(|| 3-x|-| x+||2)^{2}=25$

$\Leftrightarrow(3-x)^{2}+(x+2)^{2}-2|3-x||x+2|=25$

$\Rightarrow x^{2}-x-\left|-x^{2}+x+6\right|=6$

What to do next?.....

**Edit**
*after seeing the comments I got the idea*,

So, it is clear that $-x^{2}+x+6<0,$ i.e. $-x^{2}+x+6 \geq 0$

$(x-3)(x+2) \geq 0$

So, $x \leq-2 \& x \geq 3$

$\therefore \mathrm{x} \in(-\infty,-2] \cup[3, \infty)$

**Correct me ,If I am wrong**

Comment: What you got can be written as $\left|x^{2}-x-6\right|=x^2-x-6$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for squaring. Squaring has a risk of introducing extraneous solutions. Instead we can say
\begin{align*}
|3-x|-|x+2|&=\pm 5 \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Now consider three cases:

1. $x \geq 3$. In this case equation (1) becomes
   $$-3+x-x-2=\pm 5 \implies -5=5 \text{ OR } \color{red}{-5=-5}$$
   Because of the latter, $\color{red}{x \geq 3}$ is a solution interval.

Now do the same for $-2 \leq x < 3$ and $ x < -2$.

Comment: Squaring is fine, as far as extraneous solutions go, if you add the condition that the RHS is $\ge0$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I never said it is not fine. What I said is that there is no need and one has to be cognizant of the fact that it can introduce extra stuff.

Comment: If $x\ge 3$, then $|3-x|=x-3$.

Comment: @mathlove Thanks for pointing out the silly error I made.

Answer (score 0):

One can also approach the absolute-value expression "from the inside out".  The definition of an absolute-value function leads us to write
$$ |3 \ - \ x| \ \ = \ \  \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 3 \ - \ x  \ , & \text{for} \ \ x \ < \ 3 \\ x \ - \ 3  \ , & \text{for} \ \ x \ \ge \ 3   \end{array}\right.  $$
and
$$ |x \ + \ 2| \ \ = \ \  \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} -(x \ + \ 2)  \ , & \text{for} \ \ x \ < \ -2 \\ x \ + \ 2  \ , & \text{for} \ \ x \ \ge \ -2   \end{array}\right. \ \ . $$
The "real-number line" is thus divided into three intervals (the "cases" for the inequality).  The difference of terms can then be expressed as
$$ |3 \ - \ x| \ - \ |x \ + \ 2| \ \ = \ \  \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \ (3 \ - \ x) \ - \ [ \ -(x \ + \ 2) \ ] \ = \ 5 \  \ , & \text{for} \ \ x \ < \ -2 \\ \ (3 \ - \ x) \ - \ (x \ + \ 2)  \ = \ 1 \ - \ 2x \  \ , & \text{for} \ \ -2 \ \le \ x \ < 3     \\ \ (x \ - \ 3) \ - \ (x \ + \ 2)  \ = \ -5 \  \ , & \text{for} \ \ x \ \ge \ 3   \end{array}\right. \ \ \ . $$

We see immediately from this that $ \ x < -2 \ $ and $ \ x \ge 3 \ $ are solution intervals for $ \  | \ |3 \ - \ x| \ - \ |x \ + \ 2| \ | \  =  \ 5 \ \ . $  For the second interval, we can check that $ \ 1 - 2·[-2] \ = \ 5 \ \ , $ so $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ $ is a solution as well, and also that
$$ -2 \ < \ x \ < \ 3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 4 \ > \ -2x \ > \ -6 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 5 \ > \ 1 \ - \ 2x \ > \ -5 \ \ , $$
so there are no other solutions.  Thus, the complete solution is $ \ x \le -2 \ $ and $ \ x \ge 3 \ \ . $

We could also consider this graphically.  The function $ \ |3 \ - \ x| \ = \ | \ -(x \ - \ 3) \ | \ $ is equivalent to $ \ |x \ - \ 3| \ \ , $ so we can plot $ \ y \ = \ |3 \ - \ x| \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ |x \ + \ 2   | \ $ as versions of the absolute-value function $ \ y \ = \ |x| \ $ "shifted" horizontal "to the right" by 3 units [the blue curve in the graph below] and "to the left" by 2 units [the green curve], respectively.  We see that for $ \ x \ \le \ -2 \ \ , $ the blue curve is "above" the green one by 5 units [ $ \ |3 \ - \ x| \ - \ |x \ + \ 2| \   \  =  \ +5 \ $ ] and that the blue curve is "below" the green one by the same amount   $ [ \ |3 \ - \ x| \ - \ |x \ + \ 2| \   \  =  \ -5 \ $ ] for $ \ x \ \ge \ 3 \ \ . $  (The red curve is the graph of the difference of absolute-value terms.)

[image]

Comment: Or you could just use the triangle inequality $|a-b| \ge | |a|-|b| |$ with equality when $ab \ge 0$. Set $a=x+2, b = x-3$